# How do I find a Sea Pickle in Minecraft Wii U Edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I looked everywhere but cannot find a sea pickle. do I have to look underwater sense I am afraid of elder guardians or is it not in that particular version?

Answer (score 0):

[Sea Pickles](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sea_Pickle) will be a feature in the upcoming patch 1.13 also known as "Update Aquatic".

I don't know which version runs on the Wii U but I doubt they are ahead of the PC.

Answer (score 0):

Sea Pickles are not actually in Minecraft Wii U edition. I honestly have no idea what a sea pickle is....probably because I don't keep up with the other versions of Minecraft. But yeah, sea pickles are not in Minecraft Wii U Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Sea Pickles will be a part of the Aquatic update, like others have mentioned, but the Aquatic update will be the [last update for older consoles](https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/update-aquatic-coming-legacy-console-editions).

> Arriving a little while after the initial launch, players on PlayStation 4 Edition, PlayStation 3, Xbox 360, PS Vita and Wii U will all receive the Update Aquatic. With the exception of PlayStation 4 Edition, this will mark the last big effort to keep those editions up to date with our newer versions of the game.

So if you wish to continue to play the most up to date versions of Minecraft, upgrade your hardware.